# Calculate on go or save a cache for binary_checksum

Tags: sql-server, wcf, hash, sql-server-2012

We will be synching two different web apps with common functionality using sort of `Merkel Tree` algorithm using `binary_checksum` and wcf web services.

So the proposed workflow is following,

- On both systems if any of desired Table updated ? a database trigger will update a hash table used to store hashes of all desired tables
- At a different time (any time) sync begins between both web apps, we will be using calculated hash from this common hash table instead of calculating on the go

***Is it a common practice to store calculated hash instead of calculating them on the go ?***

I already created 2 demo tables 2 columns each with 100,000 rows and calculated hashes using code below, to me it's super fast but am I missing any concepts here like what if DB is busy at particular times etc.... ?

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS BCH FROM Table_1;
```

**Edit**

Another reason for using WCF for comparison of hashes is because we are not simply or directly synching tables, but events take place in system using coding based on what's changed.

Comment: SQL Server offers change tracking already. A lot cheaper and more reliable than checksums. Besides, `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is just a *checksum*, not a hash. You can google for cases where different text produces the same checksum. That makes it a bad choice for a Merkle hash.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both systems are not connected and we are comparing Binary hashes using WCF services, how change tracking going to help with comparison, but I am also going to google it, thanks :)

Comment: You *don't* need hashes if you already know which rows have changed and how. You can gather the changed rows from one machine and send it to the other. If you calculate/store hashes on the service, why mention `binary_checksum` at all? Just store the calculated hash as a `varbinary` column.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Services can't permanently store hashes, they will be just querying them from temp_hash table as described in question, and I am going to look into how to use change tracking now :)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean This has to be done through web services, so I am not so worried about that at this point :)